# read.table does not import all columns even with fill = TRUE

Tags: r

Essentially a machine outputs some values and I need to be able to run this script to put on the necessary headers that is then fed into another program. Unfortunately I cannot changed the format of the input or output.

Here is my code, ive simplified it down to the minimum to replicate my error, im sure its something really simple, just has driven me insane. I have attached simplified .txt files of my inputs here https://files.fm/u/8jgde7kp

```
DATA <- file.choose()  
DATA <- read.table(DATA, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, na.strings="--", header=FALSE, sep = "\t")

HDR <- file.choose()  
HDR <- read.table(HDR, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, na.strings="--", header=FALSE, sep = "\t", fill = TRUE)

FULL <- rbind(HDR,DATA)
```

etc etc

The issue is that for some reason, even with Fill = True, when it reads in the headers (also generated by another program) it drops the last column and pushes it to a new row. Row 11 should in fact be the fourth column of row 10. Obviously then the rbind doesn't work each time because of the difference in columns.

[image: image of what DATA imports]

So essentially there is something wrong with how I am importing the header data, currently my work around is to go in each time and manually enter more tabs into the first row.

Important note: The inputs will always vary in the number of columns depending on the work we are doing, but no matter what, row 10 of Header.txt and the data file will always have the same number of columns.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You cannot use rbind unless the number of columns and their names are the same.

Comment: If you don't want the DATA in a dataframe then use readLines rather than read.table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably the best way to do what you describe without damaging the structure of either (header or data) by attempting to coerce to `data.frame` or similar. Since it's being read by another program, presumably whether or not the output has class `data.frame` is irrelevant.

```
header <- readLines("header.txt")
data <- readLines("data.txt")

fileConnection <- file("combined.txt")
writeLines(c(header, data), fileConnection)
close(fileConnection)
```

Here we just read the lines of the header and data separately, preserving their respective structures. Then `c()` concatenate them together, and write out to `.txt`. You could add a new line character `writeLines(c(header,"\n",data), fileConnection)` to add a new row between the header and data.

Also, this should work regardless of the number of rows/columns of either header or data. Both the header and data remain tab-delimited.

```
[Header]
GSGT Version    2.0.3
Processing Date 6/29/2018 2:31 PM
Content     CLassified
Num SNPs    9999
Total SNPs  9999
Num Samples 9999
Total Samples   9999
[Data]
SNP Name    Sample ID   Allele1 - AB    Allele2 - AB
NGHS1   Sample1 A   A
NGHS1   Sample1 A   B
```

Answer (score 0):

Use explicitly defined column names by `col.names`:

```
> HDR <- read.table(
+   "Header.txt",
+   stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
+   na.strings="--",
+   header=FALSE,
+   col.names = paste0("V", 1:4), # <- here
+   sep = "\t",
+   fill = TRUE)
> HDR
                V1                V2           V3           V4
1         [Header]                                            
2     GSGT Version             2.0.3                          
3  Processing Date 6/29/2018 2:31 PM                          
4          Content                     CLassified             
5         Num SNPs              9999                          
6       Total SNPs              9999                          
7      Num Samples              9999                          
8    Total Samples              9999                          
9           [Data]                                            
10        SNP Name         Sample ID Allele1 - AB Allele2 - AB
```

However, as it is mentioned in the comments, there is a better way to do it, than to force  a 4-column structure on your input. You need to read the header using `readLines`, for example, and then append your DATA to it:

```
HDR <- readLines("Header.txt")
## save your result
resultFile <- "result.txt"
writeLines(HDR, resultFile)
write.table(DATA,
            file = resultFile,
            append = TRUE, # <- keeps previous content, i.e. HDR
            col.names = FALSE)
```

Comment: I think that is giving the OP what they think they want but they should instead be advised that it is the wrong approach.

Comment: Thanks, this does work, and thanks 42 for your advise.

Comment: Good point, 42! I edited accordingly. However, there will be some people who will indeed need to force read.table to have certain column number, so I keep both ways.